# WEBDAV Securit - 2FA ubuntu server

Tags: server, security, https, webdav, two-factor-authentication

at the moment I'm creating a server based on WEBDAV and I have a question:

Is it possible to add 2FA to my network map drive or some other type of additional intrusion prevention?
Apart from the firewall, password, ssl and encrypted files of course. (data will be sent outside the LAN).

(Any other advice on the security of sending data over the Internet is welcome :) )

Comment: Welcome to AU. Please provide details of your os / hardware. Thank you.

Comment: OS - the latest version of ubuntu.                                                                                                                            I can detail hardware specification later.